# Why one of the elements of my code never updates?

Tags: python, physics, simulator, particle-system

Idk why but I fail everytime I try to simulate particle interactions, it's a to do in my life. I only succeeded once while using qb64 btw. How can I fail so much in such a classical problem?

I'm sorry to make a general question, I know they doesn't work here, but I'm really done with my code, may be you could tell me with less effort what I'm doing wrong.

The specific problem is that in a two particle system under attractive force and equal mass only one of the elements moves and the other stays put (dv !==0 but self.speed==[0,0]) while both should move together. However this behaviour changes If the particle number is greater than two, instead of one specific particle not moving, it moves but very slightly.

It probably could be an updating problem inside nested loops, I know there are such in python but I don't remember exactly the mechanics. So here is my code:

```
import pdb
import time
import random
from math import isclose
from graphics import *
ulimit=1000
universe=GraphWin('',1000,1000)
#universe.Yup()
import numpy as np
global field
global space
field={}
space=[]
c=100
class relation:
  def __init__(self):
      self.value={}
  def setvalue(self, one, another,value):
      self.value[str(one)+str(another)]=value
  def getvalue(self, one, another):
      return self.value[str(one)+str(another)]

class matter:
  def __init__(self,position=np.array([0,0],dtype=float),speed=np.array([0,0],dtype=float),mass=0):
        self.speed=speed
        self.position=position
        self.mass=mass
  def net(self):
        self.field=np.array(0,0)
        for particle in space:
            if not particle==self:
                 self.field+=field.getvalue(self,particle)



for point in range(2):
    x=250+(150*random.random())
    y=250+(150*random.random())
    space.append(matter([x,y]))

field=relation()


def draw_point():
  print(field)
  #quit()
  for x in range(1000):
    for y in range(1000):
        pt=Point(x,y)
        kolor=color_rgb(round(field[x][y][0])*20,round(field[x][y][1])*20,0)
        pt.setFill(kolor)
        pt.draw(universe)


def update_field():
 for particle1 in space:
    for particle2 in space:
      if not particle1==particle2:
         field.setvalue(particle1,particle2,np.array((0,0)))

 for particle1 in space:
   for particle2 in space:
       if not particle1==particle2:
         dx=particle2.position[0]-particle1.position[0]
         dy=particle2.position[1]-particle1.position[1]
         sx=np.sign(dx)
         if sx==0:
            sx=1
         sy=np.sign(dy)
         if sy==0:
            sy=1
         if dx==0: #isclose(a,b)
            force=np.array((0,sy/(dy**2)))
         if dy==0:
            force=np.array((sx/(dx**2),0))
         if (dx==0) and (dy==0):
             force=np.array((sx*c,sy*c))
         if not dx*dy==0:

            a=abs(dx/dy)
            distance=np.sqrt((dx**2)+(dy**2))
            force=np.array( (sx*a/(distance**2),sy/(a*(distance**2) )))
         field.setvalue(particle1,particle2,force)



def interact():
  print('interaction')
  for particle1 in space:
    dv=0
    for particle2 in space:
     if not particle1==particle2:
      x=particle1.position[0]
      y=particle1.position[1]
      dv+=field.getvalue(particle1,particle2)
    if np.array_equal(list(dv),[0,0]):
        pdb.set_trace()
    old=particle1.speed
    particle1.speed+=dv
    if np.array_equal(particle1.speed,old):
       print(dv, particle1.speed,particle1)      
       pdb.set_trace()
    particle1.position+=particle1.speed/2
    if (abs(particle1.position[0]) >ulimit) or (abs(particle1.position[0])>ulimit):
        print(particle1.position)
        space.remove(particle1)
        

def moveTo(shape, newCenter):
    oldCenter = shape.getCenter()
    myOldX, myOldY = oldCenter.getX(), oldCenter.getY()
    myNewX, myNewY = newCenter.getX(), newCenter.getY()
    moveX = myNewX - myOldX
    moveY = myNewY - myOldY
    shape.move(moveX, moveY)
    return shape

global rep
rep={}
for particle in space:
    pt=Point(particle.position[0]*5,particle.position[1]*5)
    cir=Circle(pt, 25)
    rep[particle]=cir
    cir.draw(universe)
print (rep)
while True:
  
  for particle in space:
      pt=Point(particle.position[0],particle.position[1])
      moveTo(rep[particle],pt)
      universe.update()

  update_field()
  print(field.value)
  interact()
```

Comment: what 'element' doesn't update? The question here is hard to understand

Comment: @AnthonyL Same I. A matter class element inside the list "space", one of those referenced as particle1-particle2 inside the loops. <__main__.matter object at 0x7fa3e63afe50>

Comment: you don't need to put global at the outermost declaration of the variables, but inside namespaces when you refer to it again, you do

Comment: Only field and space are globals, seems reasonable to me even from a philosophical point. Now tell me that that is the cause of the error and I'll change it, otherwise save the minor improvements for when the issue is solved.

Comment: @AnthonyL do you mean like field=relation(); global field ??

Comment: check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp) w3 page on global. I'd use variables `field` and `space` like how the last example does

Comment: @AnthonyL so I have to declare global inside every function? would that solve my issue?

Comment: Yes inside each namespace, and if it doesn't solve it, you are one step closer to figuring out why with better code

Comment: Sorry for clarification, what do your mean with namespace? Isn't a way in python to make a global variable really global?

Comment: variables outside the scope of a function wont change or update after the function returns. To make the updates permanent you must first declare them as global inside the function

Comment: @AnthonyL did that, nothing changed.

Comment: Could this be a rounding problem? Like a precision error, or casting error?

Comment: Not a constructive rant but python always has an excuse to not do the job while you have to do extra job. I see the point for different scopes but for this task it-s just an overkill. would be much easier to declare something like "general x" instead of global x.

Comment: @AnthonyL pretty much seems like, but nothing too obvious, I only used rounding for passing graphics. Could be a loss between type conversions though. The only function that used rounding it-s not in use.

Comment: I wish I could be of more help, but you posted a lot of code with multiple potential reasons to be causing this problem

Comment: @AnthonyL It-s weird because if I add more particles, like 3 or more, the problem almost disappears, kind of, instead of some particle not moving a couple now move very slow. Seems to be the last one of inside the space list.